# Lucene search on svn repository

Tags: svn, lucene

I have got an **svn** repository and some selected  **svn** file path list. How to do Lucene content search on **svn** file path list. here is more detail

How do I index svn repository and files using Apache Lucene? Are there plugins/extension (as part of apache project or third party project that will help me into this )? I appreciate any tutorial or any sample.

Comment: Could you please furnish more details on what you want to search for?

Comment: Do you know how to use Lucene in general?

Comment: Sorry for the less description. I got an svn repository and svn file path with version(as a java string), but physical file is in svn repository . How to do a content search in those svn repository files using JAVA. For example : exactly like  [SVNSearcher](http://svn-search.sourceforge.net/), but SVNSearcher not a comercial free.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot do a content search on a file using file path list using Lucene. If you want to do a content based searching in Lucene first index all the svn repository files into a index along with the content and their file paths. Then you can use Lucene search to do content based searching on them.

Please refer [Lucene Usage Demo](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/demo/overview-summary.html#overview_description) on how to use lucene to index and search files.

If you need the full tutorial please refer here [Apache Lucene Tutorial.](http://computergodzilla.blogspot.com/2012/12/apache-lucene-how-to-use-apache-lucene.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seeems like svn repository is very sophisticate and I fear of lucene having index reader on svn file, also there may be possibility of svn file getting lock or corruption. Does lucene has project to handle svn file content search?

Comment: Index the files of svn that are in your selected file list in some other location. It will not hamper any of the svn files.